# Why does membrane potential depend on permeability?

Tags: potential, voltage

It sounds like a biochemistry question, but I'm really asking about the physics point of view:

it is said (and modeled by the Goldman equation) that the effect of an ion concentration on a cell membrane potential is dependent on the permeability of that ion across the cell.

For a concrete example, this graph shows the effect of increasing Na+ concentration outside of a cell on the resting membrane potential (that is, when Na+ permeability is very low).

[image: membrane potential against Na+ outside concentration]

I can't make sense of this: why doesn't the potential change? I don't get what the importance of permeability is, voltage is a difference between two electric potentials, if I introduce a large amount of positive charge outside of a barrier then I expect the voltage across the barrier to change. As far as I understand voltage doesn't require a flowing current, therefore permeability isn't needed to affect electric potential.

As a side note (and adding to my confusion) I don't even get why the small change that is shown is positive, the Na+ is being added on the outside, so the relative jump should get even more negative (as the inside is even more negative compared to the outside).